# simpleIOC sing default constructor

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm-light, ioc-container

I use `mvvm light` toolkit, and I have a problem with the `simpleIOC`. I would like to resolve an interface, but there are two constructor of the class, and the `simpleIOC` does not know which is the default. How can I sign the default constructor of a class?

```
//ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            ////if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            ////{
            ////    // Create design time view services and models
            ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
            ////}
            ////else
            ////{
            ////    // Create run time view services and models
            ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            ////}
```

this is with ninject, as you see, there are 2 cunstructor, and I want to use the first so I have to sign it, cause of there are 2 constructor, the ioc does not know, which is had to inject.
I want to do this, with the SimpleIOC from mvvm light toolkit, because now I use the Ninject IOC

```
 [Inject]
        public RepositoryFactories()
        {
            repositoryFactories = GetSpecFactories();
        }

        public RepositoryFactories(IDictionary<Type, Func<DbContext, object>> factories)
        {
            repositoryFactories = factories;
        }
```

Comment: Why does that class have two constructors? How does this class look like? How does your registration look like?

Comment: this is the ioc container name
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
I have an abstract factory, and that has 2 constructor, one for injection, one for the get basic

Comment: If would really like to help you, but without any code examples it's not possible to give any specific feedback and possible solutions.

Comment: I modified the problem text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **[PreferredConstructor]** instead of **[Inject]**.

According to documentation from the [source code](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras%20%28NET35%29/Ioc/PreferredConstructor.cs) of the MVVM Light Toolkit it is exactly what you are looking for:

```
/// <summary>
/// When used with the SimpleIoc container, specifies which constructor
/// should be used to instantiate when GetInstance is called.
/// If there is only one constructor in the class, this attribute is
/// not needed.
/// </summary>
//// [ClassInfo(typeof(SimpleIoc))]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Constructor)]
public sealed class PreferredConstructorAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

PS. Looks like CodePlex prefer links with actual spaces and brackets over special HTML characters (like %20 and %28) so the link to the original source file is a bit not complete. Anyway you could find file at this location:

```
https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras (NET35)/Ioc/PreferredConstructor.cs
```